# Plot bar chart by group side-by-side with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, bar-chart, histogram

I have a dataframe in R with the following dataset structure (dummy data):

```
Years    Spain     Russia     Malta
1995     31.3      45         84.3
2009     32.4      4          90
```

And I want it to be plotted in a bar chart where X is the years and for the year 1995, the values of each country are represented by vertical bars side-by-side, the same for 2009. My code for plotting the data is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = years)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=1, position="dodge") +
  theme_minimal()
```

However my bar chart is being plotted like the image below, 1) where the XX has every year between, 2) no colours to differentiate countries and 3) the 3 countries are obviously not side by side for each year. How can I represent this in R?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update: base R version:

```
row.names(df) <- df$Years
df <- df[ , 1:ncol(df)]
df <- as.matrix(df)

barplot(height = df[,-1], 
        col = row.names(df),
        legend = rownames(df),
        args.legend = list(x = "topleft"),
        beside = TRUE)
```

[image]
What you need is a `geom_bar` or `geom_col` not `geom_histogram`:

First bring your data in long format with  `pivot_longer`
then use `geom_col` with `position = "dodge`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Years
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Years), y= value, fill=name))+
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

[image]

Comment: what is the y=value? The values are the multiple values for each country. What should I put in there? How could I do this without the tidy verse package?

Comment: Please see my update!